# Hide Objects List in Django Admin Delete Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

When deleting an item from the Django Admin page, the delete form shows:

1. Summary
2. Objects

The Objects list shows all the objects and their related objects. The list is pretty huge and difficult to navigate when deleting multiple records.

Is there a way to hide the "Objects" list from the delete form in Django?

I have looked around, but the only option I have found is to override the template. Is it possible to achieve this through ModelAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

The options as you've found are to either override the template (and likely the view itself to avoid the additional queries) or [disable the existing action](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#disabling-actions) and create your own version.